# Blending Edges of Two Layer Images?

Tags: gimp, layers, blending

I've ran into a predicament in Gimp 2.8, trying to figure out how to blend two edges of an image together. I have three different layers, two of them I'm wanting to blend together, and one I'm wanting to avoid due to severe color difference. In the image you'll notice the little line between the two images, and I'm wanting to combine to a good middle. The dark grey you see at the top stretches down to the bottom of the triangle, and that's what I want to avoid. I've googled and read multiple articles, but they don't seem to cover exactly my problem, but only combining two images entirely. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you use  a layer mask on the top layer where the black->white transition covers exactly the overlap area:

[image]